# How to set Google Chrome to default with Default Applications?

Tags: google-chrome, midori, apps

The Web Browser dropdown only shows Midori as available.

Answer (score 2):

Open **Chrome**.

In the top right, click the **Chrome menu**

Click **Settings**.

In the "Default browser" section, click Make Google Chrome the default browser.

If you don't see the button, Google Chrome is already your default browser. later try to restart your computer and go to **System configuration** > **Aplications** and check if the Chrome Browser appear in the list:
[image: Chrome Browser as default]

Comment: Google Chrome reports it's the default but links continue to open Midori. The dropdown under Applications only shows Midori as available but Google Chrome is running on my system.

Comment: I have the same issue - chrome is not listed in that dropdown with the latest version of Elementary -- did you ever find a way to fix it?